# JPA create object using existing superclass object

Tags: inheritance, jpa, merge

I have a little issue with my JPA project. I have two classes Employee and Member which extend Person. That works fine with JPA but when I tried to merge an Employee using existing Person Object(in reality is a member) to create an Employee I had Duplicate Entry Exception. How can I manage this issue? I don't have any idea!!

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable{
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      protected int id;
      @Column(name = "last_name")
      private String name;
      @Column(name = "first_name")
      private String firstName;
      @Column
      private String address;
      @Column
      private String tel;
      @Column
      private String email;
      @Column(name = "bar_code")
      private String barCode;
      @Column(name = "birth_day")
      private java.sql.Date birthDay;
      private int sex = 1;

      Person(Person p){
            this.id = p.id;
            this.barCode = p.barCode;
            this.address = p.address;
            this.birthDay = p.birthDay;
            this.firstName = p.firstName;
            this.name = p.name;
            this.email = p.email;
            this.sex = p.sex;
            this.tel = p.tel;
      }
      ....
}

@Entity
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable{
    public Employee(String name, String firstName, String address, String numTel,
        String email, Date birthDay){
        super(name, first_name, address, numTel, email, birthDay);
    }

    public Employee(Person p){
        super(p);
    }
}


@Entity
public class Member extends Person implements Serializable{
    public Member(String name, String firstName, String address, String numTel,
        String email, Date birthDay){
        super(name, first_name, address, numTel, email, birthDay);
    }

    public Member(Person p){
        super(p);
    }
}


 Person p = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id = 1", Person.class).getResultList().get(0);
 Employee e= new Employee(p);
 em.getTransaction().begin();
 em.merge(e);
 em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Words cannot explain what code can.

Comment: Here is some code, I hope that will help

Comment: It's a good start :) Could you add the code where you actually do the merging? I don't quite understand what 'merge an Employee using existing Person Object(in reality is a member) to create an Employee' means.

Comment: Sorry to be late. I added the code merging the entity.

Comment: In Person's copy constructor, you set the id of the copy to the id of the original entity. If you want to create a new record, do not set the id, let the persistence provider do it.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I stay having the same issue ' Duplicate entry' because Hibernate tray to insert a Person already existing in the database

Comment: If your new person instance has it's id set, this is what should happen. Have you tried creating a person without setting an id?